# How to Make my Image Stretch All the Way?

Tags: html, css, image, sass, pug

I'm styling the home page of my website; I want the image (see photo below) to stretch all the way below the header. Is there any way I can do that?

Here's my index.pug file code:

```html
extends _component/layout/layout

block super-config
    -
        var active = '/'

block awesome-content
    .img
        img(src="/asset/image/pink-computer.jpg")
```

And here's my style.scss file code:

```html
.img {
    
}
```

Thanks!

[image: My website's home page]

Comment: do you want the image be the background?

Comment: Yes, I do. Do I set it to background-image?

Comment: yes...learn here:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: See here exmple:https://jsfiddle.net/ejy5ngLz/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    img{
        width:  100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

You can use this code absolutely, but the content you place after this div will appear below the image

There is also another method, you can call it as background-image

```
  img{
        background-image:  example.jpg;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

If you want the next content to appear on the above of the image, then set it as background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this one should work properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bBmWWvJquGM/maxresdefault.jpg" />
        </div>​​​​​​​​​​

        <style>
        #wrapper, img{
            width:  100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this one should work:

```
.img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

if you use **height:100%;** it will fill the section, but won't maintain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I found another fix, which was to say:

```html
.img-photo {
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(/asset/image/pink-computer.jpg);
}
```